# iPhone App with account login - Review process

Tags: ios, passwords, appstore-approval, account

I just submitted an app to the store which uses accounts to log users in to see billing info and such. I'm wondering if just emailing them the guest account info is enough, or what will happen when they begin reviewing the app and need to login.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an text area called 'Review Notes' in the metadata of an app in iTunes Connect where you can supply details about test-accounts and such.

If you already have a 'guest-account' available from the app and they can use the app (even if limited) that should be good enough for passing the Apple review.

Comment: Great, found it and the review went through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide review notes with your app submission, this is where you should provide the login details